# How to display sum of columns (where all values are decimal values) in DataTables in PHP-jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

In my PHP-jQuery DataTable, all values of the column in all rows are decimal values and also contains a "**₹**" sign before the decimal value like below:

```
+---------+
| Column  |
+---------+
| ₹ 1.20  |
+---------+
| ₹ 3.42  |
+---------+
| ₹ 9.07  |
+---------+
```

I want to display sum of the decimal values of all the columns on the table footer like below:

```
+----------------+
|     Column     |
+----------------+
|     ₹ 1.20     |
+----------------+
|     ₹ 3.42     |
+----------------+
|     ₹ 9.07     |
+----------------+
| ₹ 13.69 (Total)|
+----------------+
```

I've tried to output like above using the "`footerCallback`" function, but failed:

```
"footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
    var api = this.api(), data;

    // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
    var intVal = function ( i ) {
        return typeof i === 'string' ?
        i.replace(/[\$,₹]/g, '')*1 :
        typeof i === 'string' ?
        i : 0.00;
    };

    // Total over this page
    pageTotal = api
    .column( 4, { page: 'current'} )
    .data()
    .reduce( function (a, b) {
         return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
     }, 0 );

     // Update footer
     $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
         '&#8377; '+pageTotal +' (Total)'
     );
 },
```

It results like below on the table footer:

```
₹ NaN (Total)
```

Please help!

Comment: This will teach you to store numbers as numbers and not as strings.

Comment: Why is this taged as PHP?

Comment: Why on earth downvote this question...? People should really learn to explain their displeasures, the asker have no chance to do a better job if the downvotes not is explained.

Comment: Use the sum snippet / plugin instead, believe that would do the job and you dont have to reinvent the wheel -> **https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum()**

Answer (score 0):

If somebody it´s looking for a correct answer (many years later):

You need to change `typeof i === 'string' ?` to `typeof i === 'number' ?`

Here's a example code that's work even with filters:

```
"footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
                    var api = this.api(), data;

                    //Remove the formatting to get decimal data for summation
                    var intVal = function (i) {
                        return typeof i === 'string' ?
                            i.replace(/[\$,₹]/g, '') * 1 :
                            typeof i === 'number' ?
                                i : 0.00;
                    };

                    //Total over this page
                    pageTotal = api
                        .column(3, { filter: 'applied' })
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0);

                    //Update footer
                    $(api.column(3).footer()).html('$' + pageTotal);
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your intVal function checks if the value is a string and if it is converts it to a number, but if it's already a number then it returns 0.

Yu aren't working with integers though, decimal numbers are floats so this isn't suitable for currency addition as it will only ever return whole numbers.

Delete your whole intVal function and replace with something like this, all it does is strip anything which isn't a number or a decimal point:

```
var floatVal = function ( i ) {
    return i.replace( /[^\d\.]/g, '');
};
```

Then change this line of your pageTotal function `return intVal(a) + intVal(b);`
to this, which will add your numbers together as floating numbers instead of appending them to one another:

```
return parseFloat(floatVal(a)) + parseFloat(floatVal(b));
```

Comment: Its not working! Datatable is not loading properly now!